Number of ways of splitting people into groups
This is example 1.33 from Bertsekas' book Intro to Probability:
A class consisting of 4 graduate and 12 undergraduate students is randomly divided into four groups of 4.
What is the probability that each group includes a graduate student?
I don't understand this part of the solution:
We first determine the nature of the sample space. A typical outcome is a
particular way of partitioning the 16 students into four groups of 4. We take the term "randomly" to mean that every possible partition is equally likely, so that the probability question can be reduced to one of counting.
According to our earlier discussion, there are $\frac{16!}{4!4!4!4!}$
different partitions (multinomial method), and this is the size of the sample space.
My Question: If we are splitting 16 people into 4 groups, surely we don't care about the order of the groups so we should divide by 4! to get $\frac{\frac{16!}{4!4!4!4!}}{4!}$

So long as you are consistent, it doesn't matter.  If you want order of the groups themselves to matter (i.e. which group is "group A" vs "group B" and so on...) then you do so for both your denominator and your numerator.  If you don't want them to matter, then don't for your denominator and your numerator.  The final result will match after cancellation.
If your question is specifically about the counting problem, then the result is up to personal preference.  There can be many different equally valid ways of describing a sample space to a problem.  If your question however is about the probability problem, then it is moot.
For what its worth, I would personally not even care about all of the non-graduate students in the first place.  Imagine if you will that each group is labeled and each seat within the groups are labeled.  Then a valid way of distributing the students into the groups is going to be by telling them not only which group they go in, but also which seat.  We only then need to care about following which seats the graduate students are given.
The first graduate student can receive any seat, no issue.  Once the first graduate student has gotten their seat, then the next graduate student must get a seat from a different group.  The chance of this will be $\dfrac{12}{15}$.  Then the third will need a seat from a different group than either of the first two which happens with probability $\dfrac{8}{14}$, and the last with probability $\dfrac{4}{13}$.  The probability will then be:
$$\dfrac{12}{15}\times\dfrac{8}{14}\times\dfrac{4}{13} = 0.14\overline{065934}$$
I find this approach to be much cleaner and require far less thought and arithmetic than the approach alluded to by the book.
The answer alluded to by the book would be to consider the $\binom{16}{4,4,4,4}$ arrangements of the students in general into four labeled groups (or $\binom{16}{4,4,4,4}\cdot\frac{1}{4!}$ arrangements into unlabeled groups) and compare this to the $4!\binom{12}{3,3,3,3}$ ways to distribute them where each group gets just one grad student (or the same but divided by $4!$ if we wanted to forget about the group labels)
We get an answer of $\dfrac{~~~\dfrac{4!12!}{3!3!3!3!}~~~}{\dfrac{16!}{4!4!4!4!}} = 0.14\overline{065934}=\dfrac{~~~\dfrac{4!12!}{3!3!3!3!}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{1}{4!}}~~~}{\dfrac{16!}{4!4!4!4!}\cdot\color{red}{\frac{1}{4!}}}$, the same as before
